# Distribution of noncentrality parameter in noncentral t-distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, statistical-power, non-central

Let $X$ be a random vector $X \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma = \frac{1}{n} Id$. Find probability 
$$
P(|T| > a)$$

where $T$ has noncentral t-distribution with noncentrality parameter $\delta = \sqrt{\sum(x_i - \bar X)^{2}}$ and $n-2$ degrees of freedom.

This originally was an exercies about calculating power of test for linear regression slope. This is the step where I am stuck. The problem is how to deal with $\delta$ being random variable. I thought that maybe i can replace it with standard deviation $\delta = \frac{\sqrt{\sum(x_i - \bar X)^{2}}}{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = 1$ but i am rather sure that this is not correct

Edit: Maybe there is another thing I don't understand, I found that in linear regression predictor variables is assumed to be fixed and known. If it is true how can I compute power theoretically, without using some sort of simulation?

Comment: In a noncentral t distribution the non centrality parameter is just that - a parameter. It isn't a random variable - it doesn't have a distribution. You may need to explain more about your circumstances. Note that power is a population-relatd quantity, not a sample quantity

Comment: In slope test test statistics has noncentral t with $\delta=\frac{\beta_1 \sqrt{\sum(x_i - \bar X)^{2}}}{\sigma}$. In this particular exercise $\sigma$ and $\beta_1$ is equal to $1$. Now how am I supposed to calculate this probability(which is power of the test) when i have no imformation about sample?

Comment: If $X$ is treated as random, the unconditional distribution of the statstic is not non-central t